# How to fix SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused, when running : php artisan migrate in docker bash?

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker

I'm trying to run "php artisan migrate" in docker app container bash, after successfully installing mysql, nginx, php and etc. containers.

But this error comes up :

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = code_clan and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'B
> ASE TABLE')

This is my folder/files structure :

```
> docker-my-app(folder)
  > docker(folder)
    > nginx(folder)
      > default.conf
    > php-fpm(folder)
      > Dockerfile
  > src(folder)
    > www(folder)
      > Laravel Project Files...
      > **.env**

  **docker-compose.yml**
```

This is my composer file (docker-compose.yml):

```
version: '3.8'

services:

  nginx:
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    image: nginx
    tty : true
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./src/www:/usr/share/nginx/html:delegated
      - ./docker/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    networks:
      - thenetwork
  
  app:
    build: ./docker/php-fpm
    container_name: myapp
    tty : true
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: myapp
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    networks:
      - thenetwork
    working_dir: /usr/share/nginx/html
    volumes:
      - ./src/www:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ./data/upload:/storage/uploads
  
  memcached:
    image: memcached

  mysql:
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    image: mysql:5.6
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - mysqlvolume:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./data/mysql-import:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    environment:
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pwd
        - MYSQL_HOST=localhost
        - MYSQL_PORT=3306
    networks:
      - thenetwork

  redis:
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    image: redis



#Docker netwtorks
networks:
  thenetwork:
    driver: bridge
volumes:
  mysqlvolume:
    driver: local
```

This is my .env file (inside the root of laravel project):

```
APP_NAME=MyApp
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:generatedKey
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=daily
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=lara_app
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=pwd
...
```

Inside docker-my-app cmd, I run :

```
 docker exec -it myapp bash
```

And inside there, I run :

```
/usr/share/nginx/html$ php artisan migrate
```

all the containers, including mysql are running successfuly.
And the error mentioned at the beginning happens.

Can you figure out what happens here?

Comment: change `127.0.0.1` to `mysql` in .env and run `php artisan optimize`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After trying different ways:

1. like setting up an .env file for docker-compose.yml
2. and trying to clear the cache of laravel config and cache files inside docker myapp bash , like this:

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

3. at the end changing the **DB_HOST** constant inside **laravel root .env** file from **127.0.0.1 to mysql**, solved my problem and migration and everything related to mysql is fine now. The reason was that I named the mysql service inside docker-compose.yml file to mysql.

.env file :

```
APP_NAME=MyApp
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:generatedKey
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=daily
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
**DB_HOST=mysql**
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=lara_app
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=pwd
...
```

Comment: I have the same setup and ran into the same issue.   When running migrations it is maybe a little less convenient to do it from bash within the container like you are doing vs. directly from the host.    Initially, I would execute some commands from the host side, like composer, npm, etc.  Later, I just added composer and npm to my container build so I'm not dependent upon having my dev tools installed on the host.  I think it is relatively easy to install composer from the DockerFile:  RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

Comment: An additional note is that if your mysql ports are something other than this : 3306:3306 for example like this : 8806:3306 then you will need to use the docker's mysql container name for the DB_HOST=mysql_container_name. Hope it helps someone :-)

Answer (score 0):

I am on MAMP. I just changed the port to 8889 and the password. It works

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan migrate
```